# How to change style of selected React-router link?

Tags: reactjs

I have NavBar.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "./navBar.sass";

function NavBar() {
  return (
    <div className="NavBar_container">
      <nav className="NavBar">
        <Link
          to="/CreateReview"
          className={(isActive) =>
            "selected" + (!isActive ? " unselected" : "")
          }
        >
          <div className="NavBar_img">
            <img src="./create_review_icon.png" alt="create_review" />
          </div>
          <p className="NavBar_title">Create Review</p>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/Hotels" className="NavBar_item">
          <div className="NavBar_img">
            <img src="./main_page_icon.png" alt="main_page" />
          </div>
          <p className="NavBar_title">Reviews</p>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/MyAccount" className="NavBar_item">
          <div className="NavBar_img">
            <img src="./my_account_icon.png" alt="my_account" />
          </div>
          <p className="NavBar_title">My account</p>
        </Link>
      </nav>
      ;
    </div>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

And some styles:

```
.NavBar
    position: fixed
    z-index: 9999
    display: flex
    justify-content: space-between
    width: 400px
    height: 75px
    padding: 15px 25px 0 25px
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.81)
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px
    &_container
        width: 450px
        margin: 0 auto
    &_item
        text-decoration: none
        &:hover , &:active
            .NavBar_title
                transition: 0.2s all
                color: #DAAD86
                border-bottom: 1px solid #DAAD86
            .NavBar_img
                transition: 0.2s all
                transform: scale(1.1)
    &_img
        width: 35px
        margin: 0 auto
    &_title
        text-align: center
        color: white
        padding-bottom: 5px

.selected
    background-color: blue

.unselected
    background-color: red
```

**I'm trying to set up my NavBar so that the selected link changes style, nothing works right now, what's wrong? I would like the text under the image to change its color and become underlined (as it is done in the :hover classes). I did this according to the React-Router documentation, maybe I missed something?**

Answer (score 0):

In your app.jsx file, or wherever you have your navbar component rendering, use the useLocation hook provided by 'react-router-dom' to get the current page. You can then pass it to your navbar as props and give the links the 'selected' class if the current page === the page the link points to.

Comment: It would be better to provide a part of code or demo as demonstration in your answer.